# Remove escape of quotes with Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: javascript, c#, json, serialization, json.net

I serialize my dataset by this code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

     var json=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds);
     return json;
```

But, i get unnecessary escaping of quotes. I understand the reason why it is happening.

But, is there a way to avoid it

So, how can i change the current result:

```
{"d":"{\"Table\":[{\"Id\":4,\"adsc_title\":\"مجله\"},{\"Id\":5,\"adsc_title\":\"رمان\"},{\"Id\":6,\"adsc_title\":\"رایانه\"}],\"Table1\":[{\"Id\":55,\"Name\":\"بانه\"},{\"Id\":57,\"Name\":\" دهگلان\"}]}"}
```

I want to remove escape characters to parse JSON by javascript.

Let me know if more clarity is required.

Thanks much in advance.

Comment: It looks like you may be double-serializing your JSON.  Is `d` a property of a `DataSet`, or of some wrapper class?  I can't reproduce this just by serializing a test `DataSet`, so might you make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem?

Comment: Sometimes visual studio shows escape characters but those aren't really there. I suppose you see this result in debug mode?

Comment: @WPMed yes , debug mode.

Comment: Than it's just an artefact of Visual Studio as it was in my case. Just do what you want with the JSON, will work!

Comment: @WPMed  But how can I parse this format of JSON by javascript or JQuery?

Comment: @WPMed How can I access to this JSON elements? `code {"d":"[{\"aa\":\"11111111111111111111\",\"bb\":\"222222222222222222\"},{\"aa\":\"33333333333333333333\",\"bb\":\"444444444444444444\"}]"} `

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the problem is that the form of that JSON look like  [the return of a manually serialized json](http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/).

Comment: How can I access to this JSON elements?   `code  {"d":"[{\"aa\":\"11111111111111111111\",\"bb\":\"222222222222222222\"},{\"aa\":\‌​"33333333333333333333\",\"bb\":\"444444444444444444\"}]"}`

Comment: As Dave Ward's excellent article says , ASP.NET automatically JSON serializes your service methods’ responses, even if their result is an object or collection of objects. So what I would do is try to get a good align between server code and client , if that is not possible (maybe you don't have access to the sending side) you can try a second round of deserialization with jquery:

Comment: but your fist option should be to try to use automatic [de]serialization mechanism of ASP.